# Drawing a bar gauge

Tags: cocoa-touch, user-interface, drawing

How can I draw a bar gauge like this image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for(int i=1;i<30;i++)
{
    imgview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];
    imgview.frame=CGRectMake(10+i*10, 10, 10, 20);
    imgview.tag=i;
    [self.view addSubview:imgview]; 
}
   do this loop with some animation
```

Comment: Thanks, I wnat to draw static bar, fixed value. How to do it?

Comment: fix the loop accordingly how much length u need

Comment: Works perfect! But I want to add some spacing between the images, so that it looks similar to above img..how do I do it?

Comment: simply change the x-postion mean imgview.frame add or multiply greater than 10 u can get

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Animating a [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with NSArray on a timer. 
If you are not interested in using UIImageView and want this strictly programming, you could do a [drawRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101) and create square that are displayed according to the timer and NSArray data.

Its harder to get help when you don't explain your own effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom progress bar with custom progress image and trace image as  [image] and white colored image for progress and then put an UIImageView with image like this [image] above the progressview then the white color image will progress below this image and it look likes just like the progress that you want..

The bared  images is png and I have cut it not in a good way but you can make it better.